# Visit Nginx sites-enable without domainname in place

Tags: drupal, nginx, debian

I was wondering, I regularly set up a new Drupal site in Nginx, I download the files, get the database in place and then.... I wait... for the DNS to resolve because I have no idea how to access the site without going through the domain name as stated behind "server_name".

Does anybody know how to access all the sites in sites-enabled without using a proper domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to resolve domain name to IP locally. You can use `hosts` file for it. Just edit `/etc/hosts` file if your home OS is Linux, or `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if Windows.
Add `ip.of.ur.sever domain.name.com` line, save file and restart browser.

Comment: Thats sounds like a very good solution, thanx, I'll try it next time. (In the mean time, all DNs have resolved.)